# Nanoc compile rule with regex

Tags: regex, compilation, rules, nanoc

I have files with filenames begining with `controls-`, like `controls-dark.png` for example, but this rule does not catch them:

```
compile '/gallery/*/', :rep => :thumbnail do
  filter :thumbnailize, :width => 200 unless /controls-/.match(item[:filename])
end
```

Why does this not gives a match?

So at the end I get `controls-dark.png` converted to thumbnail although it should be excluded by this rule.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was working, problem was in routing, so it did not convert my `controls-dark.png` to thumbnail, only changed its filename to `conrols-dark-thumbnail.png`.

I used the same check in routes, so:

```
route '/gallery/*/', :rep => :thumbnail do
unless /controls-/.match(item[:filename])
    item.identifier.chop + '-thumbnail.' + item[:extension]
else
    item.identifier.chop + '.' + item[:extension]
end
```

Now files containing `controls-` in their filename get only copied over, without `-thumbnail` suffix appended.